# jquery dialog without a form

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui, web-applications, lotus-notes

I have two problems.

1. I am developing web application in Lotus, and Lotus likes to take control of the situation and insert code where it sees fit.
2. I am using Jquery UI to open a modal dialog window.  If I simply open and close the dialog, then try to submit the parent form, I get a __click is not an object.  When I took a closer look at the code, Lotus wraps the entire page in  tags.  Then jquery has the form code in it to serve up the dialog.  So html forms don't like to live inside of each other?!?

Question.

Can I build a jquery UI modal dialog without using the form tags?  Is there an attachment to the  tag that the UI lib needs to create the dialog?  I've taken the tags out, but what are the side effects?

Thanks for the help, btw it only breaks in IE.  Of course.

Added by Lotus
`<form method="post" action="/IS/GIFormDev.nsf/giForm-Step3?OpenForm&amp;ideaNumber=000036-2010" name="_DominoForm">
<input type="hidden" name="__Click" value="0">CN=Kris Mitchell/O=xxxx`

Jquery Form

```
 <div id="formContainer" style="display:none;">
<div id="dialog-form" title="Copy Other Managers">
    <form>
    <p>text</p>
    <fieldset>
        <form>
        <div id="ccIngManagerDiv">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you supply a code sample?

Comment: Not really, it would be a whole page of code. I will try to add some code snippets to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options (hard to give more details without seeing more code). But you can place your jQuery dialog div at the very end of the Notes form, and precede it with a closing  tag. You could also not use a form tag at all in the jQuery dialog div - just set up a div with what you want displayed in the jQuery dialog. Include a button with a JS event handler that writes into fields on the main form, and submits the main form (if you don't have any rich text on the form, then you can just use Javascript to submit the main form - otherwise, you need to be careful to use the Domino generated __click function).

Comment: I actually used your solution of not using the form tags around the jquery form.  I realized that I can use the jquery events for the buttons to control the closing of the form, and was already handling the overhead of pushing the results out to Lotus fields.  Thanks for the help. +1 +Accepted Solution